# SQL command works but the same command with EntityFramework do not?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**Hi,**

If I run the in my database :

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    Ads AS a 
INNER JOIN AdCategories AS ac 
    on (ac.Id = a.CategoryId) 
INNER JOIN Location AS l 
    on (l.Id = a.UserLocationId) 
WHERE 
    (l.LevelOrder LIKE '2/3/5/%') AND 
    (a.Title LIKE '%' OR a.Description LIKE '%') AND 
    a.InactivatedDate IS NULL AND 
    a.PublishedDate IS NOT NULL AND 
    a.EndDate >= '2012-02-04 17:01:37' AND 
    a.EndDate >= '2011-11-04 16:55:26' AND 
    ac.LevelOrder Like '7/15/33/36_%'
```

This will return 2 rows but when running the same command with Entity Framework

```
context.CreateQuery<Ad>(sqlCommand, parameters.ToArray()); 
output = ads.ToList();
```

I get nothing?

This is how the SQL statement looks like :

```
SELECT VALUE a 
FROM 
    Ads AS a 
INNER JOIN AdCategories AS ac 
    on (ac.Id = a.CategoryId) 
INNER JOIN Location AS l 
    on (l.Id = a.UserLocationId) 
WHERE 
    (l.LevelOrder LIKE @locationLevelOrder0) AND 
    (a.Title LIKE @searchS OR a.Description LIKE @searchS) AND 
    a.InactivatedDate IS NULL AND 
    a.PublishedDate IS NOT NULL AND 
    a.EndDate >= @CurrentTime AND 
    a.EndDate >= @fetchAdsTo AND 
    ac.LevelOrder Like @categoryLevelOrder
```

The parameters looks like this :

1. `LocationLevelOrder0 = 2/3/5/%`
2. `searchS = %`
3. `CurrentTime = {2012-02-04 17:31:34}`
4. `fetchAdsTo = {2011-11-04 17:31:34}`
5. `categoryLevelOrder = 7/15/33/36/_%`

Why do I not get any results with the Entity Framework while I do in SQL manager? And what does the select value a stand for? If I remove it there will be thrown an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first your query you compare LevelOrder with `'7/15/33/36_%'` and in the second one with `7/15/33/36/_%` that is a different string. Is this a transcription mistake or is the issue?

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, If I run 7/15/33/36/_% I will not get any hits anymore. The string I try to mach is "7/15/33/36/X" where X my be any string, maby "7/15/33/36/69/78/99" or "7/15/33/36/100/152/158". Do the _& have a special meaning in SQL? Else It should only be to remove the _?

Comment: Yes, in SQL `_` is a wildcard for only one character in `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Okay, so with this 7/15/33/36/_% I say match 7/15/33/36/ + one wildcard at least but also grant strings with more wildcards? I will try to exclude the _ and see if that works in the long run. Thanks for helping!